# Ansible playbook with become_method=pbrun not working

Tags: ansible, pbrun

I am a beginner on Ansible. I am trying to run command as a db user and we have pbrun setup for changing users in my company.

Below is how my pbrun policy is defined as :

```
[ RunAs User ]       [ Command ]
root                 /bin/su - couchbase
root                 /bin/su - enterprisedb
```

From ansible.cfg (only sharing privilege_escalation part):

```
[privilege_escalation]
become=true
become_method=pbrun
become_user=''
become_ask_pass=False
become_flags: '/bin/su - enterprisedb'
```

From playbook :

```
$ cat ping.yml
- name: Test
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  any_errors_fatal: false
  tasks:
  - shell: whoami
    register: output

  - debug:
      msg: "{{output.stdout}}"
```

Below is how I am running playbook.
ansible-playbook -i sample.host1.list ping.yml -k -vvvv

Output :

```
$ ansible-playbook -i sample.host1.list ping.yml -k -vvvv
ansible-playbook 2.8.12
  config file = /home/ads_username/ansible_work_dir/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/adshome/ads_username/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Sep 26 2019, 13:23:47) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
Using /home/ads_username/ansible_work_dir/ansible.cfg as config file
SSH password:
setting up inventory plugins
host_list declined parsing /home/ads_username/ansible_work_dir/sample.host1.list as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /home/ads_username/ansible_work_dir/sample.host1.list as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
yaml declined parsing /home/ads_username/ansible_work_dir/sample.host1.list as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
Parsed /home/ads_username/ansible_work_dir/sample.host1.list inventory source with ini plugin
Loading callback plugin debug of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/debug.pyc
Loading callback plugin profile_tasks of type aggregate, v2.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/profile_tasks.pyc

PLAYBOOK: ping.yml ******************************************************************************************************************************************
Positional arguments: ping.yml
ask_pass: True
become_method: pbrun
inventory: (u'/home/ads_username/ansible_work_dir/sample.host1.list',)
forks: 5
tags: (u'all',)
verbosity: 4
connection: paramiko
timeout: 10
become: True
1 plays in ping.yml

PLAY [Adding VM to inventory] *******************************************************************************************************************************
META: ran handlers

TASK [shell] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/ads_username/ansible_work_dir/ping.yml:6
Wednesday 10 November 2021  15:21:32 -0700 (0:00:00.053)       0:00:00.053 ****
<server_name.region.company.com> ESTABLISH PARAMIKO SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None on PORT 22 TO server_name.region.company.com
<server_name.region.company.com> EXEC /bin/bash -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /tmp `"&& mkdir /tmp/ansible-tmp-1636582892.39-15614-57850062632655 && echo ansible-tmp-1636582892.39-15614-57850062632655="` echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1636582892.39-15614-57850062632655 `" ) && sleep 0'
<server_name.region.company.com> Attempting python interpreter discovery
<server_name.region.company.com> EXEC /bin/bash -c 'echo PLATFORM; uname; echo FOUND; command -v '"'"'/usr/bin/python'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python3.7'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python3.6'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python3.5'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python2.7'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python2.6'"'"'; command -v '"'"'/usr/libexec/platform-python'"'"'; command -v '"'"'/usr/bin/python3'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python'"'"'; echo ENDFOUND && sleep 0'
<server_name.region.company.com> Python interpreter discovery fallback (pipelining support required for extended interpreter discovery)
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/commands/command.py
<server_name.region.company.com> PUT /adshome/ads_username/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-155953Afqz2/tmpgNQgMu TO /tmp/ansible-tmp-1636582892.39-15614-57850062632655/AnsiballZ_command.py
<server_name.region.company.com> EXEC /bin/bash -c 'chmod u+x /tmp/ansible-tmp-1636582892.39-15614-57850062632655/ /tmp/ansible-tmp-1636582892.39-15614-57850062632655/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'
<server_name.region.company.com> EXEC /bin/bash -c 'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-sgemmsfapenzvcsbxdnbjneynirmhzkl; echo "/usr/bin/python /tmp/ansible-tmp-1636582892.39-15614-57850062632655/AnsiballZ_command.py"|pbrun /bin/su - enterprisedb  && sleep 0'
<server_name.region.company.com> EXEC /bin/bash -c 'rm -f -r /tmp/ansible-tmp-1636582892.39-15614-57850062632655/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
[WARNING]: Platform linux on host server_name.region.company.com is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python, but future installation of
another Python interpreter could change this. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information.

fatal: [server_name.region.company.com]: FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "rc": 2
}

MSG:

MODULE FAILURE
See stdout/stderr for the exact error


MODULE_STDOUT:

Last login: Wed Nov 10 15:21:02 MST 2021
/usr/bin/python: can't open file '/tmp/ansible-tmp-1636582892.39-15614-57850062632655/AnsiballZ_command.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied



PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************
server_name.region.company.com : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Wednesday 10 November 2021  15:21:35 -0700 (0:00:03.141)       0:00:03.194 ****
===============================================================================
shell ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 3.14s
/home/ads_username/ansible_work_dir/ping.yml:6 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please help guide me on what is wrong in my setup and if it is possible to make this work without changing anything in my pbrun policy.

Comment: Hi BeginnerSumB welcome to SO. Ansible's [`become` must be unrestricted](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/become.html#privilege-escalation-must-be-general)

Comment: Hmm. If ansible is trying to do something which is not defined in pbrun policy then it should throw the pbrun error. Can you please help me understand what id ansible uses in remote machine for prep work before it switches to different id using pbrun??